# Background Music that stops playing when video is played

Tags: html, html5-audio

ツ
Hi, I was wondering how I can add background music to a webpage that would <strike>fade away</strike> stop when I play an embedded video <sup>(especially Youtube)</sup> and then start again when the video gets over.

The code I use to embed audio is:

> `<embed src="example.mid" autostart="true" loop="true">`

I'm also aware that HTML5 has an audio tag, but can somehow that produce the effect I need (which is the music stopping when a video is played)?

<sup>Don't worry, I want to use this on an html based presentation and not an actual webpage.
EDIT: I've edited this question so as to make  it a bit more clear.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `<audio>` tag you can control the volume programmatically via Javascript.

Specifically, the issue how to fade out the volume has an jQuery based example here:

[HTML5 <audio> playback with fade in and fade out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7451508/315168)

Comment: Ok, thank you, but how can I set the volume to zero when a video starts playing?

Comment: Yes. Start video playback via Javascript and just before you call video.play() do video.volume = 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too good at HTML5 but you can use eventlistners in javascript for this. onload event to load a function that will play the music and an onclick event on the video to remove the audio when the video is played.

Comment: I'm not too good at javascript, so a code snippet would be nice.