# How to apply a fade effect in HTML5 mute button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, audio

I have a mute button that simply mute a HTML5 audio object. It does mute the track but I like to add a fade in/out effect.
I tried it by adding `audio.animate({volume: 0}, 2000);` but its not working.

Any idea?

Thank in advance!

```js
audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "http://myst729.qiniudn.com/within-temptation_pale.mp3"
audio.play();

$(".mute").on("click tap", function(){
 if (audio.muted) {
            audio.animate({volume: 1}, 2000);
            audio.muted = false;
            $(this).text("mute");

        } else {
            audio.muted = true;
            audio.animate({volume: 0}, 2000);
            $(this).text("unmute");
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="mute">mute</button>
```

Comment: put every thing in animate function

Comment: @KarthikeyanSekar like this `audio.animate({volume: 1, audio.muted = false}, 2000);` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 <audio> playback with fade in and fade out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451508/html5-audio-playback-with-fade-in-and-fade-out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `audio` object should be a JQuery-object in order to use the JQuery [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function. You can do that by changing `audio.animate` to `$(audio).animate`.

Also the `audio.muted = ...` statements turn off/on the music instantly, so you won't hear the animations.

A working example:

```js
audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "http://myst729.qiniudn.com/within-temptation_pale.mp3"
audio.play();

$(".mute").on("click tap", function() {
  var $btn = $(this);
  
  var muted = audio.muted;
  if (muted) audio.muted = false; // It cannot be animated if it's muted
  
  $btn.prop('disabled', true); // Optional
  $(audio).animate({volume: muted ? 1 : 0}, 2000, function() {
    audio.muted = !muted;
    $btn.text(muted ? "mute" : "unmute");
    $btn.prop('disabled', false); // Optional
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="mute">mute</button>
```

Comment: Apparently audio cannot be animated if `audio.muted = true`, so the unmute-animation didn't work properly. I have improved my answer by fixing this ;)