# Fade in/ out audio on <section> while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, audio, webm

So this is more of a question asking for some direction.
Remember the 90s where horrible websites slapped you with full volume audio on page load?
Yeah, I want to do that... but with a twist.

I want to have audio attached to a section and to fade the audio in and out as you enter and exit the section. As if you are walking down a street full of party houses with an empty lot in between. I would imagine that is accomplished by JS, but I can't find anything so far.

Can someone please point me in the general direction?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451508/html5-audio-playback-with-fade-in-and-fade-out in combination with mouseover and mouseout events

Comment: You can try with jQuery